# Navigationcontrol in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to develop an application for iphone 3G which requires flip from one page to another page.I can navigate from one page to another page by using navigation control but it gives the animation from "right" to "left" when page changes. Can i flip it in just opposite direction means the page will animate from "left" to "right" when requires to go back to previous page? the animation effect must be there.the application is navigation based not view based.And the back flip action must be in a button not in navigation bar button.
I think it can be done as we can do it by navigation bar button,but got to put that logic in normal button. pretty confused about the logic...
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote an answer to another similar question which may be of help:
[Push Next Detail UIView without going back to parent UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612870/push-next-detail-uiview-without-going-back-to-parent-uitableview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-[UINavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:]` to reproduce the effect of the built-in "Back" button.  Or there's `-[UINavigationController popToViewController:animated:]` if you want to go further back than one view controller.

Answer (score 0):

For going from one view to another you can use [UINavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES] and when you u want to go to previous view you can do is write teh following line on button click event  [UINavigationController popToViewController:animated:YES] and  hide your back button in the navigation bar item as per your requirement.